# Force quicker timeout for remote MySQL connections?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Had an issue recently where a major fire at a datacentre destroyed one of our machines. While this server is now offline all of the other servers on our network are still functional, although this has brought to light a problem that I'm hoping to find the answer for.

Is it possible to reduce the amount of time PDO will wait before reporting that the connection failed?

In my particular scenario there are others servers that rely on remote MySql connections to retrieve data from the destroyed server in order to display certain things. Now I have measures in place to handle the situation when the requested data isn't supplied, but have never had to deal with a machine being unreachable until now.

So right now I'm in the situation where my online servers are hanging on page load due to the destroyed server being offline.

Is there any preference or setting that can be provided when trying to make the initial remote connection where you say "return false without throwing a script breaking error after 5 seconds" for example?

I call my connections through a db class :

```
protected static function getDB()
{

    static $db = null;

    if ($db === null) {
        $dbhost = DB_HOST;
        $dbuser = DB_USER;
        $dbpass = DB_PASS;
        $dbname = DB_NAME;

        try {
            $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8mb4",
                           $dbuser, $dbpass);

            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    return $db;
}
```

Like this...

```
$db = static::getDB();
```

I'm presuming that I can simply return false in the catch exception instead of echoing the error message which answers half of my question if true, but is it possible to speed up the time it will wait before throwing the exception in the event of an unreachable machine?

EDIT

I found this and tried it...

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT, '5');
```

... but it makes no difference to the timeout whatsoever? Does this setting only relate to local connections maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer myself...

At first I found this and added it but it made **NO** difference whatsoever to the time taken before bomb out in my situation, maybe it works in others though?

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT, '5');
```

But the answer that **DID** work for me was dropping this in right before the database connection :

```
ini_set("default_socket_timeout", 5);
```

Hope it helps somebody else.